# Jython 2.5 and virtualenv on windows

Tags: windows, virtualenv, jython-2.5

I have installed Jython 2.5 on Windows, then setuptools and finally virtualenv (1.8.4) using easy_install. Now I am trying to create a new virtual environment using the following command line :

> jython \Lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.5.egg\virtualenv.py jython_env

But the creation of the new virtual environment fails with the following error:

> os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'symlink'

I guess this is because Windows does not handle symlinks but does anyone already meet this issue, is there any workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but for the benefit of others who may read this page...

I recently encountered the same issue with jython2.7.0 and managed to get around this by hacking jython's Lib/os.py  (mine was under C:\jython2.7.0) to add at the bottom:

```
def symlink(target, file):
    ''' Just copy files in Windows, 
        maybe you could use mklink system calls instead '''
    from shutil import copy
    copy(file, target)
```

Don't forget to remove the compiled bytecode version of the os module otherwise the changes won't be loaded.

Then try running `virtualenv -p /path/to/jython.exe jython-env-name`.

Note that you should either have python2*.dll from your jython bin/ directory in your system PATH , have the dll registered or else copy the dll into your new virtualenv's bin directory.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue and used this workaround, but had to switch `target` and `file`